# 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

I am a newbie to asp.net and don't know very well. I am just working on a project. As I try to create a new category. I face an exception.

'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but not handled in the code.

This is my Action Method.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Category category)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(category);
    }
```

This is the Category Class

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category name is required")]
    [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "The category name can be maximum 45 characters long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This is the DbContext

```
 public class DbClass : DbContext
{
    public DbClass()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbClass>());
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

I couldn't get why this exception is appearing and how to fix this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: look at the inner exception.

Comment: I even don't know how to do that. Would be kind enough to help me in that please?

Comment: depends on your IDE. but you can also simply write a recursive method that writes you the exception message and then the message of the inner exception (unless it's null) to any output device you want, and catch,write and re-throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your section of code in a try catch block.

```
try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
catch (Exception /* ex */)
{
    //Log the error (uncomment ex and place a break point on the line below to check the inner exception.  Ideally log the error so it can be reviewed.)
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
}
```

Comment: I suspect that'd be your solution to any kind of error?

Comment: It would, it would prevent an unhandled exception from occurring.  The inner exception is a property of the exception that has been thrown.